# @Html.Raw Putting HTML Outside the Enclosed Tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
 <p class="red">@Html.Raw(@Model.Description)</p>

@Model.Description is <p>Some text here</p>
```

When it renders I get the following:

```
 <p class="red"></p>
<p>Some text here</p>
```

Why is it rendering outside the `<p class="red"> <p>` tags?

Comment: Nesting `<p>` elements is invalid html. The browser sees this and "fixes" the layout for you.

Comment: Yeah thanks! I nested inside <div> and it worked!